# Firebird UPDATE a field using conditions of other table

Tags: sql, sql-update, firebird, firebird2.5

I have two tables in Firebird with the following fields:

```
TABLEA: KEY, ITEM, LAST_SALE_DATE 

TABLEB: KEY, ROT
```

Both are related by the key. They refer to the same item using the key field.

I want to update `TABLEB.ROT='A' where TABLEA.LAST_SALE_DATE>01/01/2016`.

I can't figure how to make the statement, please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways you can do this. First of all you can correlate the [update](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-dml-update) of `TABLEB` by doing an existence check on `TABLEA`:

```sql
update TABLEB b set b.ROT = 'A' 
where exists (
  select 1 
  from TABLEA a 
  where a.KEY = b.KEY and a.LAST_SALE_DATE > DATE '2016-01-01')
```

Another way would be to use [`MERGE`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-dml-merge):

```sql
merge into TABLEB b
  using TABLEA a
    on a.KEY = b.KEY and a.LAST_SALE_DATE > DATE '2016-01-01' 
  when matched then
    update set b.ROT = 'A'
```